# Vertx Mysql Client prepareQuery with in statement

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x

I am trying to execute query with vertx with in sql statement and I am failing to make it work. I don't understand how should I pass a collection of values

here is what I am trying to do:

```
MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
                .setPort(3306)
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setDatabase("innodb")
                .setUser("root")
                .setPassword("local1234");



        MySQLPool sqlPool = MySQLPool.pool(connectOptions, new PoolOptions());
        PreparedQuery<RowSet<Row>> prepare = sqlPool.preparedQuery(
                "select * from myTable where someId in (?)");
        List<String> ids = List.of("someUniqueId", "other");
        Future<RowSet<Row>> execute = prepare.execute(Tuple.of(ids));
        execute.onComplete(
                rows -> System.out.println(rows.result().size())
        );
```

When running with one value without the in (?) it is working fine
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These two queries are different:

```
select * from myTable where someId in ('123','456','789')

select * from myTable where someId in ('123,456,789')
```

The first query has a list of three discrete values. The second query has one value, a string that happens to contain commas.

A parameter can only be used to substitute for a scalar value. So when you pass a string with commas as the value, it is as if you executed the second query I showed.

To get the result you want, you need multiple parameter placeholders:

```
select * from myTable where someId in (?, ?, ?)
```

Use as many placeholders as the number of elements in the tuple.